# Set location of wwwroot folder from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-7.0

I have below code in program.cs of my .net core 7 project.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions(){
    WebRootPath="D:\\wwwroot",
});
```

I am using this code to manually set the location of wwwroot folder. How can i read the location from appsettings.json file.

Comment: we could use `builder.Configuration` to read `appsetting.json` file, so you have to define the builder before read the file....

Comment: @TinyWang it is impossible to use it before it is created =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the webroot path if you setup your project correctly. As for the appsettings, you're looking for this:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty approach would be to create another builder and use it as config:

```cs
var configuration = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args).Configuration;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = configuration.GetValue<string>("WebRoot")
});
```

But I would recommend just to use just a configuration builder and specify sources which would be used for this goal:

```
var cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);

var configuration = cfg.Build();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = configuration.GetValue<string>("WebRoot")
});
```